# Access problem on a website with login, web scraping Phyton

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, algorithmic-trading

I created a web scraping program in order to scrape information from the platform plus500 (trading platform) in order to get the real time value of the market index, the problem I had is that when I run the program:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from Config import username, password


def main():
    url = 'https://app.plus500.com/trade?innerTags=_cc_&webvisitid=d9cf772d-6ad5-492c-b782-e3fbeaf7863d&page=login' \
          '&_ga=2.35401569.1585895796.1661533386-1432537898.1661336007 '

    with requests.session() as session:
        response = session.post(url, auth=(username, password))
        pprint(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the result I get is this:

```
('{\n'
 '  "status": "Rejected",\n'
 '  "statusCode": "406",\n'
 '  "supportID": "11920948162926473185252678965843397577",\n'
 '  "ipAddress": "my IP",\n'
 '  "timeStamp": "2022-08-27 12:30:47"\n'
 '}')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see the post request is sent but I get back the status rejected and I don't know why, I created a dummy account for you, email: myrandomcode@gmail.com - Plus500_password: MyRandomCode87 - . Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the headers, if you add

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

and change

```
response = session.post(url, auth=(username, password))
```

for

```
response = session.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)
```

work.
You could check, if yu want, what headers are necessary and what not